# Can't figure out how to make edits within a particle system using scripting in Blender

Tags: python, particles, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I cannot figure out how to get the particles settings to display on the side tab like the "preview_samples" has (shown below). I'm trying specifically to change the number of particles using the same way that the viewport samples has been changed but I've tried lots of different things with no succession.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using `particles` instead of `particle_systems['NAME']` where NAME is the name of the particle system and defaults to 'ParticleSystem'.